# Java8 equivalent of Joda's ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser()?

Tags: java, java-8, jodatime

I can't figure out how to get Java8's DateTime parsing to behave like the Joda equivalent I am attempting to replace.  The issue is that Joda's `ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser();` allowed me to input as little as YYYY and it would still work (2016 would become 2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z", for example).  How can I get this same behavior from Java8?

The code is simple enough...

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat;

public class Java8OffsetDateTime {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] candidates =
        { "2016-11-21T17:54:51.841Z",
            "2016-11-21T09:54:51.841-08:00",
            "2016", // Java8 no can do?
            "2016-11", // Java8 no can do?
            "2016-11-21", // Java8 no can do?
            "2016-11-21T01", // Java8 no can do?
            "2016-11-21T01:02", // Java8 no can do?
            "2016-11-21T01:02:03" // Java8 no can do?
        };
    DateTimeFormatter JodaDateTimeFormatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser();
    for (String candidate : candidates) {
      System.out.println("\ncandidate:\t\"" + candidate + "\"");
      DateTime jodaDateTime = JodaDateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(candidate);
      System.out.println("Joda:\t" + jodaDateTime);
      try {
        OffsetDateTime java8OffsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(candidate);
        System.out.println("Java8:\t" + java8OffsetDateTime);
        long jodaMillis = jodaDateTime.getMillis();
        long javaMillis = java8OffsetDateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
        System.out.printf("jodaMillis:%d %s javaMillis:%d\n",
            jodaMillis,
            (jodaMillis==javaMillis) ? "==" : "!=",
            javaMillis);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The results are the challenge...

```
$ java -cp ~/work/joda-time-2.9.6/joda-time-2.9.6.jar:. Java8OffsetDateTime

candidate:  "2016-11-21T17:54:51.841Z"
Joda:   2016-11-21T09:54:51.841-08:00
Java8:  2016-11-21T17:54:51.841Z
jodaMillis:1479750891841 == javaMillis:1479750891841

candidate:  "2016-11-21T09:54:51.841-08:00"
Joda:   2016-11-21T09:54:51.841-08:00
Java8:  2016-11-21T09:54:51.841-08:00
jodaMillis:1479750891841 == javaMillis:1479750891841

candidate:  "2016"
Joda:   2016-01-01T00:00:00.000-08:00
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2016' could not be parsed at index 4
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1947)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1849)
    at java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse(OffsetDateTime.java:402)
    at java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse(OffsetDateTime.java:387)
    at Java8OffsetDateTime.main(Java8OffsetDateTime.java:26)

candidate:  "2016-11"
Joda:   2016-11-01T00:00:00.000-07:00
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2016-11' could not be parsed at index 7
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1947)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1849)
    at java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse(OffsetDateTime.java:402)
    at java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse(OffsetDateTime.java:387)
    at Java8OffsetDateTime.main(Java8OffsetDateTime.java:26)

candidate:  "2016-11-21"
Joda:   2016-11-21T00:00:00.000-08:00
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2016-11-21' could not be parsed at index 10
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1947)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1849)
    at java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse(OffsetDateTime.java:402)
    at java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse(OffsetDateTime.java:387)
    at Java8OffsetDateTime.main(Java8OffsetDateTime.java:26)

candidate:  "2016-11-21T01"
Joda:   2016-11-21T01:00:00.000-08:00
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2016-11-21T01' could not be parsed at index 13
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1947)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1849)
    at java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse(OffsetDateTime.java:402)
    at java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse(OffsetDateTime.java:387)
    at Java8OffsetDateTime.main(Java8OffsetDateTime.java:26)

candidate:  "2016-11-21T01:02"
Joda:   2016-11-21T01:02:00.000-08:00
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2016-11-21T01:02' could not be parsed at index 16
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1947)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1849)
    at java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse(OffsetDateTime.java:402)
    at java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse(OffsetDateTime.java:387)
    at Java8OffsetDateTime.main(Java8OffsetDateTime.java:26)

candidate:  "2016-11-21T01:02:03"
Joda:   2016-11-21T01:02:03.000-08:00
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2016-11-21T01:02:03' could not be parsed at index 19
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1947)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1849)
    at java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse(OffsetDateTime.java:402)
    at java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse(OffsetDateTime.java:387)
    at Java8OffsetDateTime.main(Java8OffsetDateTime.java:26)
```

How do I get rid of those `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException`s from the "Java8 no can do?" cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Tunaki for suggesting the alternative syntax. This will help you parse your input values that you have provided. Adjust accordingly.

```
OffsetDateTime java8OffsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(candidate, offsetDateTimeFormatter );

DateTimeFormatter customOffsetDateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("yyyy[-MM][-dd['T'HH[:mm[:ss]]]][.SSSXXX]")
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 1)
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 0)
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 0)
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS, ZoneOffset.of("-08:00").getTotalSeconds())
            .toFormatter();
```

Test Case: **(-06:00 Offset)**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
public class App 
 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] candidates =
            {"2016-11-21T15:54:51.841Z",
                 "2016-11-21T09:54:51.841-06:00",
                    "2016", // Java8 no can do?
                    "2016-11", // Java8 no can do?
                    "2016-11-21", // Java8 no can do?
                    "2016-11-21T01", // Java8 no can do?
                    "2016-11-21T01:02", // Java8 no can do?
                    "2016-11-21T01:02:03" // Java8 no can do?*/
            };

        DateTimeFormatter customOffsetDateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("yyyy[-MM][-dd['T'HH[:mm[:ss]]]][.SSSXXX]")
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 1)
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 0)
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 0)
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS, ZoneOffset.of("-06:00").getTotalSeconds())
            .toFormatter();

    org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter jodaDateTimeFormatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser();
    for (String candidate : candidates) {
        System.out.println("\ncandidate:\t\"" + candidate + "\"");
        DateTime jodaDateTime = jodaDateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(candidate);
        System.out.println("Joda:\t" + jodaDateTime);
        try {
            OffsetDateTime java8OffsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(candidate,customOffsetDateTimeFormatter);
            System.out.println("Java8:\t" + java8OffsetDateTime);
            long jodaMillis = jodaDateTime.getMillis();
            long javaMillis = java8OffsetDateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
            System.out.printf("jodaMillis:%d %s javaMillis:%d\n",
                    jodaMillis,
                    (jodaMillis == javaMillis) ? "==" : "!=",
                    javaMillis);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output: **(-06:00 Offset)**

```
    candidate:  "2016-11-21T15:54:51.841Z"
    Joda:   2016-11-21T09:54:51.841-06:00
    Java8:  2016-11-21T15:54:51.841Z
    jodaMillis:1479743691841 == javaMillis:1479743691841

    candidate:  "2016-11-21T09:54:51.841-06:00"
    Joda:   2016-11-21T09:54:51.841-06:00
    Java8:  2016-11-21T09:54:51.841-06:00
    jodaMillis:1479743691841 == javaMillis:1479743691841

    candidate:  "2016"
    Joda:   2016-01-01T00:00:00.000-06:00
    Java8:  2016-01-01T00:00-06:00
    jodaMillis:1451628000000 == javaMillis:1451628000000

    candidate:  "2016-11"
    Joda:   2016-11-01T00:00:00.000-05:00
    Java8:  2016-11-01T00:00-06:00
    jodaMillis:1477976400000 != javaMillis:1477980000000

    candidate:  "2016-11-21"
    Joda:   2016-11-21T00:00:00.000-06:00
    Java8:  2016-11-21T00:00-06:00
    jodaMillis:1479708000000 == javaMillis:1479708000000

    candidate:  "2016-11-21T01"
    Joda:   2016-11-21T01:00:00.000-06:00
    Java8:  2016-11-21T01:00-06:00
    jodaMillis:1479711600000 == javaMillis:1479711600000

    candidate:  "2016-11-21T01:02"
    Joda:   2016-11-21T01:02:00.000-06:00
    Java8:  2016-11-21T01:02-06:00
    jodaMillis:1479711720000 == javaMillis:1479711720000

    candidate:  "2016-11-21T01:02:03"
    Joda:   2016-11-21T01:02:03.000-06:00
    Java8:  2016-11-21T01:02:03-06:00
    jodaMillis:1479711723000 == javaMillis:1479711723000
```

Comment: This would be cleaner using the `[...]` syntax for optional parts. It looks like `yyyy-MM-dd['T'HH[:mm[:ss]]][.SSSVV]`

Comment: Hmmm.  ```java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2016-11-21' could not be parsed at index 10``` when I try to send "2016-11-21" through this.  I take the DateTimeFormatter that comes out of this builder and just give it to ```OffsetDateTime.parse(candidate, dtFmt);```, no?

Comment: I ran exactly the same way you mentioned. it works fine here. Added the test case back to the answer.

Comment: @Veeram yeah...I'm doing something wrong.  Even at that, it looks like my use case really isn't supported without big backflips in Java8.  Thanks for the reply.  I'm going to play some more.  Maybe Joda was "helping" me too much in the first place

Comment: @Veeram your DateTimeFormatterBuilder is really close, but for the candidates that pass, the Java8 millis don't match the Joda millis for any but the first candidate (the question has been restructured to show this).  If I can figure out why your format builder struggle on the case... ```candidate: "2016-11-21T09:54:51.841-08:00"
Joda: 2016-11-21T09:54:51.841-08:00
Java8: 2016-11-21T09:54:51.841Z
jodaMillis:1479750891841 != javaMillis:1479722091841``` I think we have a winner!

Comment: Updated the offset seconds and change the date formatter pattern to use offset(XXX). Updated test case and output for my offset(-06:00). All should be good now.

Comment: Thing to note. Joda formatter is DST aware. This is the case b/c ISO Joda Date Time combines both  offset date time and zoned date time into joda date time whereas Java 8 has two separate classes for modeling offset and zone date time. I'll wait for you to confirm if you want zoned date time formatter or offset date time formatter.

Comment: Anyone looking for something to replace `ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser` where you don't control the input, beware. There are a couple of cases that joda-time parses that this code doesn't: `2016-11-02T22:00:00.000`, `2016-11-02T22:2:3`

Answer (score 2):

This will parse all of your dates except the somewhat funky **2016-11-21T01**. If you *really* need that have a look at the way `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` is constructing the `ISO_TIME` formatter. It uses an optional seconds field. Copy it and make the minutes field optional too.

```
DateTimeFormatter isoDateParser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .parseCaseInsensitive()
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
        .optionalStart()
        .appendLiteral('T')
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_TIME)
        .toFormatter();
```

Answer (score 2):

`DateTimeFormatter` is your class. However, it takes some getting used to this new java.time package. I worked with it and after a while I found it very flexible and powerful. I wrote a little article where I described a general idea on how to attempt to parse a String of unknown format to a Date. Here is the link: [Java 8 java.time package: parsing any string to date](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/java-8-javatime-package-parsing-any-string-date-michael-gantman?trk=pulse_spock-articles)

Comment: "```DateTimeFormatter```...takes some getting used to..." truer words have not been spoken.  The DateTimeFormatter is the key.